# Extrapolating OpenCV 'warpPerspective' from a smaller to larger image

Tags: c++, image, opencv, computer-vision, matrix-multiplication

Can a transformation matrix applied to a given image be reused on a scaled version of that same image?

To explain:  I'm successfully using 'cv::findHomography' to compute a 3x3 homography matrix 'Href' between an orthographic reference image and distortion-corrected photo, by first collecting correspondences between both images:

```
Href = findHomography(mpts_2,
mpts_1,
cv::RANSAC,
Settings::getHomography_ransacReprojThr(),
outlier_mask);
```

For a sample of the photo input and the orthophoto reference, see below.  This is an archaeological computing project in which we are creating Egyptological reference for all the walls of a temple built by Ramses II in Thebes, Egypt:

[image: Input photo (top), orthophoto reference (bottom)]

With the above matrix, I am able to use 'cv::warpPerspective' to create an interpolated image that correctly mimics the pose of the orthomosaic reference object -- see the image below, at right.

I believe the code provided below yields correct results (see code section A), but I would now like to apply the same 'Href' matrix to a larger version of the same input image 'src', above.

Is this possible?

My attempt to scale the results from the earlier transformation on the proxy image to apply it to the full resolution photo leads to distortion as shown below at left, contrasted with the correct result at right:

[image: An incorrect result (left), with my desired result for reference(right)]

To summarize, I am able to transform a smaller proxy image but am unsure if the same matrix can be used on the larger, full-resolution version of the image.

**Code Section A**

This is the working code to transform the proxy image according to the orthographic reference image.  Most of the code here relates to sizing and offsetting the output image; the 'cv::warpPerspective' call is at the end of the block:

```
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix
cv::namedWindow(REMAP_WINDOW, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); // create homography display window
bool redraw = true;
// load image associated with current image
src = cv::imread("input.jpg", 1); 
dst.create(src.size(), src.type()); // create destination and the maps
// Identify source image corners
std::vector<cv::Point2f> obj_corners(4);
obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
obj_corners[1] = cvPoint(src.cols, 0);
obj_corners[2] = cvPoint(src.cols, src.rows);
obj_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, src.rows);
std::vector<cv::Point2f> scene_corners(4);
cv::perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, Href); // Transform source image corners by Href to find transformed bounds
int minCols = 0, maxCols = 0, minRows = 0, maxRows = 0;
for(int i=0; i < scene_corners.size(); i++)
{
//cout << "scene_corners.at(i).y: " << scene_corners.at(i).y << "scene_corners.at(i).x: " << scene_corners.at(i).x << endl;
if(maxRows < scene_corners.at(i).y)
maxRows = scene_corners.at(i).y;
if(minRows > scene_corners.at(i).y)
minRows = scene_corners.at(i).y;
if(maxCols < scene_corners.at(i).x)
maxCols = scene_corners.at(i).x;
if(minCols > scene_corners.at(i).x)
minCols = scene_corners.at(i).x;
}

int imageWidth = (maxCols-minCols)+30;
int imageHeight = (maxRows-minRows)+30;
double w = (double)imageWidth, h = (double)imageHeight;
int f = 500;
int x = -minCols; // This is an approximation only!
int y = -minRows; // This is an approximation only!

// Projection 2D -> 3D matrix
cv::Mat A1 = (cv::Mat_<double>(4,3) <<
1, 0, -w/2,
0, 1, -h/2,
0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1);

// Camera Intrinsics matrix 3D -> 2D
cv::Mat A2 = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,4) <<
f, 0, w/2, 0,
0, f, h/2, 0,
0, 0, 1, 0);

// Translation matrix on the X and Y axis
cv::Mat T = (cv::Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
1, 0, 0, x,
0, 1, 0, y,
0, 0, 1, 500,
0, 0, 0, 1);

// Apply matrix transformation
cv::Mat transfo = A2 * (T * A1);

// Apply image interpolation
cv::warpPerspective(src, dst, Href * transfo, cv::Size(imageWidth, imageHeight), CV_INTER_CUBIC);

imshow(REMAP_WINDOW, dst);
```

**Code Section B**

This second section shows my non-working attempt to apply the 'Href' matrix to a scaled image (that is, a full resolution photo, not the smaller proxy):

```
src = cv::imread("C:\\Users\\insight\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\find-object\\bin\\Release\\genies\\Img4913_pt.jpg", 1);
dst.create(src.size(), src.type()); // create destination and the maps 
// Scale existing min/max cols/rows to fit larger image
int imageWidth = ((maxCols-minCols)*(src.cols/image.cols))+30; // Arbitrary border of 30 pixels
int imageHeight = ((maxRows-minRows)*(src.rows/image.rows))+30;
double w = (double)imageWidth, h = (double)imageHeight;
cout << "original image width: " << src.cols << ", original image height: " << src.rows << endl;
cout << "transformed image width: " << imageWidth << ", transformed image height: " << imageHeight << endl;
int f = 500;
int x = (minCols*(src.cols/image.cols))*2; // This is an approximation only!
int y = (minRows*(src.rows/image.rows))*2; // This is an approximation only!

vector<cv::Point2f> corners;
corners.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
corners.push_back(cv::Point2f(image.cols, 0));
corners.push_back(cv::Point2f(image.cols, image.rows));
corners.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, image.rows));

// Corners of the destination image
vector<cv::Point2f> output_corner;
output_corner.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, 0));
output_corner.push_back(cv::Point2f(dst.cols, 0));
output_corner.push_back(cv::Point2f(dst.cols, dst.rows));
output_corner.push_back(cv::Point2f(0, dst.rows));

// Get transformation matrix
cv::Mat Hscale = getPerspectiveTransform(corners, output_corner);

int j = 0;
x = -14500;
y = -9500;
int z = 4000;
int xfactor = 0;
int yfactor = 0;
int width = dst.cols;
int height = dst.rows;

// Projection 2D -> 3D matrix
cv::Mat A1 = (cv::Mat_<double>(4,3) <<
1, 0, -w/2,
0, 1, -h/2,
0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 1);

// Camera Intrinsics matrix 3D -> 2D
cv::Mat A2 = (cv::Mat_<double>(3,4) <<
f, 0, w/2, 0,
0, f, h/2, 0,
0, 0, 1, 0);

// Translation matrix on the X and Y axis
cv::Mat T = (cv::Mat_<double>(4, 4) <<
1, 0, 0, x,
0, 1, 0, y,
0, 0, 1, z,
0, 0, 0, 1);

// Apply matrix transformation
cv::Mat transfo = A2 * (T * A1);

warpPerspective(src, dst, Href * Hscale * transfo, cv::Size(imageWidth, imageHeight), CV_INTER_CUBIC, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, 0);
cv::imwrite("C:\\Users\\Kevin\\Documents\\Find-Object\\image.png", dst);
```

Answer (score 0):

You code sample is a tad messy, and I will not comment on it. However the answer to your question is positive, as a homography is *only* defined up to a scalar multiplicative constant. You can convince yourself that this is in fact the case by noting that, for every homograpy H, homogeneous 2D point x and scalar s,  H * x and (s * H) * x yield the same 2D point, after dividing by the third coordinate of the result (with the exception, of course, of the point at infinity).

So you should just apply unchanged to the larger image the homography estimated on the smaller one.

However, there is a caveat: upscaling will magnify the estimation errors as well, and they may become intolerable the closer your estimated homography is to being singular.

I recommend that you start by double-checking the matches your estimation is based on.